# iPhone SDK Facebook DemoApp not startable

Tags: iphone, facebook, sdk

I feel like an idiot right now as I tried to run the DemoApp which is coming with the default facebook sdk for the iphone.

I registered a new application in facebook, took he application id and added it to he DemoAppViewConroller.m like this:

```
static NSString* kAppId = @"175223790000000";
```

Then I changed the following in the DemoApp-Info.plist:

URL types - Item 0 - URL Schemes - `Item 0 = fb[175223790000000]`

Now the app crashes everytime it tries to start. There is no warning thrown.

Does anyone know what I do wrong?

Thx and cheers
doonot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove the square brackets from URL scheme:


URL types - Item 0 - URL Schemes - Item 0 = fb175223790000000


Cheers.